# Javascript Browserify, require function and run it

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, browserify

I have this little browserify problem. I want to require a self made module and run it instantly.

Main File:

```
(function() {
    require('./modules/initScrollReveal')();
    require('./modules/initChart')();
    require('./modules/initDatamap')();
  })();
```

Module:

```
exports.initChart = function () {
  // do stuff
};
```

now i get an error with the Message 
`"require(...) is not a function`" at `require('./modules/initScrollReveal')();`

Browserify is running via Watchify with

```
watchify public-modules/res/js/main.js -o public/res/js/main.js
```

Comment: try to do it separately: `require('./modules/initScrollReveal'); initScrollReveal();`

Comment: @Kaddath then its just `initScrollReveal is not a function`

Comment: ah yes you're right, in browserify require returns the object, if you can do `var a = require('thing');`, it should be valid to do `require('thing')();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

module.exports allows the initChart function to be called like a function when required. Simply setting exports wouldn't allow the function to be exported because node exports the object module.exports references.

change

```
exports.initChart = function () {
  // do stuff
};
```

to

```
module.exports = function initChart  () {
  // do stuff
};
```

More details : [browserify-handbook#exports](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#exports)

Comment: this is interesting, in the browserified version of uglifyjs i made, i find both syntaxes, i'd like to know the details of that difference, because my uglify works, so both seem to be valid.. i even have direct exports of requires, as such `exports.inherits = require('inherits');`.. i'm curious

Comment: it worked thank you very much. Its very interesting how the first version still works in Node but not in Browserify.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
(function() {
    require('./modules/initScrollReveal').initScrollReveal();
    require('./modules/initChart').initChart();
    require('./modules/initDatamap').initDatamap();
  })();
```

if your modules looks like:

```js
exports.initScrollReveal= function () {
  // do stuff
};

exports.initChart = function () {
  // do stuff
};

exports.initDatamap= function () {
  // do stuff
};
```